# How can I pivot a view into a join so I get multiple query rows as columns in a single row?

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot

I have a view into which I am pulling properties of vehicles, such as tire size, engine capacity, color, number of doors, etc. This data is stored in multiple tables but I have simplified the data into my view.

What I am trying to achieve is to join this view to my main vehicle table so that I can select the various properties as columns in a single row.

My view:

```
Vehicle_ID  Property     Value
1           Doors        2
1           Engine Size  2 liter
1           Tire Size    50cm
1           Color        Blue
2           Doors        4
2           Engine Size  3 liter
```

And my main vehicle table:

```
Vehicle_ID  Description  Date_Bought  Owner_ID
1           BMW M3 Sport 2000/12/23   1
2           Audi A5 3XL  2015/03/19   1
```

So what I would like to get out is something like

```
Vehicle ID  Description   Date_Bought   Doors   [Engine Size]  [Tire Size]  [Color]
1           BMW M3 Sport  2000/12/23    2       2 liter        50cm         Blue
```

My overall SQL knowledge is fairly limited, I'm pretty good with JOINS and stuff, but the logic of the PIVOT command and its syntax completely escape me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the PIVOT clause, you can achieve the result like this:

```
SELECT
  Vehicle_ID,
  Doors,
  [Engine Size],
  [Tire Size],
  [Color]
FROM
  dbo.YourView
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(Value) FOR Property IN (Doors, [Engine Size], [Tire Size], [Color])
  ) AS p
;
```

Now, to join the results to your main vehicle table, you can use the above as a derived table (same as you probably did with the solution you found yourself) – or you can join the main table directly to the results of the PIVOT:

```
SELECT
  m.Vehicle_ID,
  m.Description,
  m.DateBought,
  p.Doors,
  p.[Engine Size],
  p.[Tire Size],
  p.[Color]
FROM
  dbo.YourView
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(Value) FOR Property IN (Doors, [Engine Size], [Tire Size], [Color])
  ) AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.MainVehicleTable AS m ON p.Vehicle_ID = m.Vehicle_ID
;
```

The above assumes that your view has only the three columns mentioned in your question. If there are more (e.g. time of recording/storing the property or something else), then you will probably need to replace the plain `dbo.YourView` reference with a derived table where you are pulling only those three columns:

```
...
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Vehicle_ID,
      Property,
      Value
    FROM
      dbo.YourView
  ) AS s
  PIVOT
  ...
```

Comment: How to write the same using Dynamic Query?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question because I found an answer on StackOverflow that was immensely helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343174/123729

Using the logic in the question above, the query that works for me doesn't need a PIVOT operation, just a GROUP BY and MIN (or MAX) with a CASE statement, like so:

```
Select Vehicle_ID,
    Min(Case Property When 'Doors' Then Value End) Doors,
    Min(Case Property When 'Tire Size' Then Value End) [Tire Size],
    Min(Case Property When 'Color' Then Value End) Color
From table
Group By Vehicle_ID
```

Which I was then able to JOIN on the Vehicle ID.

I hope I haven't screwed up in the faux-SQL above, and that this might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

The any Sql DBMS fast runnig pivot is just (MS SQL, you may need  replace [] with "" or something for other Sql DBMS)

```
 select Vehicle_ID 
   ,max(case Property when 'Doors' then Value end) as [Doors]
   ,max(case Property when 'Engine Size' then Value end) as [Engine Size]
   --... 
 from theView
 group by Vehicle_ID
```

Which MS SQL abbreviates to

```
select Vehicle_ID -- not pivoted, group by columns 
  ,[Doors], [Engine Size] --  == values from pivoted col surrounded with [], quotes stripped
from theView
PIVOT
(
max(value) -- the same aggregation function and the same pivoted column 
FOR Property IN ([Doors], [Engine Size]) -- values as above once again
) AS PivotTable;
```

Note the first version allows for multiple columns to be pivoted at one step. MS SQL PIVOT syntax requires multiple steps for this.